# AJAX switching HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

So I want the screen to switch from one HTML to another HTML and this is my JS code. Whenever I press the button, the screen goes blank.

I am trying to make multiple HTML pages and make it switch to the next one whenever I press a button. Please help

JS

```
function loadScreen()
{
  var load = new XMLHttpRequest();
  load.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      document.getElementById("firstScreen").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  load.open("GET", "SelectNumber.html", true);
  load.send();
}
function myFunction(load)
{
  document.getElementById("firstScreen").innerHTML = load.responseText;
}
```

Original HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Number Game</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "firstScreen">

    <h1 id ="Title" class = "title">
      The<br>Number Game
    </h1>

    <div class = "start_button">
      <h3 class = "start">START
        <input type = "image" placeholder = "START" src = "button.png" class = "button1"  onclick = "loadScreen()">
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src = "Main.js"> </script>
</html>
```

HTML2 that I am trying to make it change to

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Number Game</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Screen2">
    <p> Hello World</p>
  </div>


  <script src = "Main.js"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you run the html page? by using server or not?

Comment: @rensothearin no without using a server. Just by clicking the .html file

Comment: By using simple server, I can open that normally

Comment: @rensothearin Oh so if I use a simple server to test that out it will work fine? Thank you I will have to try that

Comment: If you use Visual Studio code, you can easily install Live Server plugin. Then run the html file with Live Server.

Comment: @rensothearin AA ty it works here XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Visual Studio code with the Live Server plugin has solved the problem!